# How to load Github parameter/properties from Jenkins pipeline without triggering the build/job

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I need to read property file from github when i select the job in Jenkins **instantaneously**.

Let say, i have **jenkins_parameter.properties** in GitHub with below value:

**environment**=None,DEV,QA,PRODUCTION**
**Testcases**=None,Smoke_test1,Smoke_test2,Smoke_test3,Smoke_test4,Smoke_test5,Smoke_test6,Smoke_test7,Smoke_test8,Smoke_test9
**Servers**=None,Server1,Server2,Server3,Server4,Server5

Now, I've a job in Jenkins. The moment when i click this job, it has to load above property from the GitHub branch with parameterization.

--> Other way it works when i trigger the build with **Pipeline script from SCM**. So Jenkins Build configuration is updated with GitHub property values.

Or we can clone the github repo into the server, use cron job to update the repo for every 1 min. And same can be achieved in the jenkins build.

But this is not my requirement.